# Overriding Django's get_form_class() method throws string error

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a class based view that is supposed to dynamically select a form based on the name of the animal.

```
UpdateAnimalView(FormMixin, DetailView):
  def get_form_class(self):
    SOME_FORMS = {
        "Dog" : "UpdateDogForm",
        "Cat" : "UpdateCatForm",
        "Frog" : "UpdateFrogForm",
    }
    animal = object
    animal_type = object.type #returns "Dog", "Cat" or "Frog"
    form_class_name = SOME_FORMS[animal_type]
    #form_class_name now takes the values "UpdateDogForm"
    #, "UpdateCatForm" or "UpdateFrogFrom"
    return form_class_name
```

However, when I run this, it seems to not to read the `form_class` but as a `string` and Django throws this error:

`'str' object is not callable`

The traceback is from the `get_context_data`. I infer the callstack is as follows:

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super(UpdateAnimalView, self).get_form()
    return form

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(UpdateAnimalView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = self.get_form()
    return context
```

How can I return the `form_class` as its correct datatype and not as a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`get_form_class` should return the actual class, not its name:

```
# import the form classes from wherever they live
from .forms import UpdateDogForm, UpdateCatForm, UpdateFrogForm
...
SOME_FORMS = {
    "Dog": UpdateDogForm,   # <- no string values here!
    "Cat": UpdateCatForm,   # <-
    "Frog": UpdateFrogForm, # <-
}
```